# Toolbox tool - IGPParameterEdit3 to browse for file

Tags: arcobjects, arctoolbox

I'm trying to implement a custom Toolbox tool in ArcGIS, and am trying to setup a custom GPParameter that will take a file type with a specific extension.

I know that [DEFileType](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriDataSourcesFile/DEFileType.htm) is available and will provide a file browser.  How do you set a filter for specific file types using this object?

I suspect this needs to be done via [IGxFilterInfo](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoDatabase/IGxFilterInfo.htm), but am unable to find any relevant documentation or examples, and am having a difficult time finding an example anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set the parameter's [Domain](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoprocessing/IGPParameter_Domain.htm) property with the appropriate domain information.

In your case, you will use the [GPFileDomain](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoprocessing/GPFileDomain.htm) class. Through its [IGPFileDomain](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoprocessing/IGPFileDomain.htm) interface, you can add acceptable file types via the [IGPFileDomain.AddType](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoprocessing/IGPFileDomain_AddType.htm) method. This method takes a string representing the file extension without the preceding dot.

The file dialog will show your "myext" (an example) extension as "File (*.myext)" filter text. You cannot (easily at least) change the "File" part of the text but that is a minor problem I guess.

Comment: That worked.  I'd like to figure out how to change the "File" part - but it may not be possible.

Comment: After some investigation I believe it is not possible. And if it is, probably with effort not worth the hassle.

Comment: If you look at the built-in tools which use DEFileType for any of their parameters, there is not a single one where the filter text is different from the standard "File (*.ext)" format...

Comment: Thanks for the updates... I've come to the same conclusion, btw

Answer (score 1):

There's a way you can do it though. If you write a custom control for the parameter and bind it to the parameter with ControlCLSID, you can add a button to the control that opens an OpenFileDialog. Evaluate the parameter's domain and set the dialog's Filter property to what you need.

Comment: btw, @petr: How did you find out about all the built-in tools that use DEFileType?

Comment: @find: Basically, I instantiated all the tools in the appropriate COM component category and examined their parameters.

Comment: Anyway, you probably should have made a comment to my post instead of making a new post..